# Why mock when you can replace an object?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to understand why I need to use mocks when I can just replace object I want to mock directly.

For example in this contrived example

```
class Child:
    def get(self):
        return {0 : "SomeDictResult"}

class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = Child()

    def get_info(self):
        return self.child.get()

def test_get_info(root : Root):
    root.child.get = lambda : {1 : "SomeOtherResult"} # This is where a mock would be

    print(root.get_info())
```

Instead of mocking, I am replacing get with an lambda function with a custom output. Why would I need to mock if I could replace the `get` function

Comment: Behind the scene replacing objects and attributes with mock objects is exactly what unit test frameworks such as `unittest` and `pytest` do. You can choose not to use them, but these frameworks make your mocking/patching code easier to develop and more readable.

Comment: Mocking is not required if an object is changed that exists during one test only. If a longer existing object is changed the change might interfere with other tests. A patched-in Mock will restore the original state automatically.

Comment: What if you want to mock an object that will be created during the run of the method being tested? What if the method that you mock doesn't return anything and you just want to check that it was called? What if you want to assert what values was the mocked method called with? You could do this all in your own way but you would be re-inventing functionality that the existing mocks already provide.